# I got value error that image has no shape while converting image to tensor for performing neural style transfer

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am using tensorflow_hub modules to perform neural style transfer and I get the error "'images' contains no shape". I don't understand where I made a mistake.

This is my code:

```py
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

content_path = r'C:\Users\Sriram\Desktop\efil.jpg'
style_path = r'C:\Users\Sriram\Desktop\download1.jfif'
content_image = plt.imread(content_path)
style_image = plt.imread(style_path)

plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.title('Content Image')
plt.axis('off')
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.title('Style Image')
plt.axis('off')

def image_to_tensor(path_to_img):
    img = tf.io.read_file(path_to_img)
    img = tf.image.decode_image(img, channels=3, dtype=tf.float32)
    
    # Resize the image to specific dimensions
    img = tf.image.resize(img, [720, 512])
    img = img[tf.newaxis, :]
    return img

def tensor_to_image(tensor):
    tensor = tensor*255
    tensor = np.array(tensor, dtype=np.uint8)
    tensor = tensor[0]
    plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
    plt.axis('off')
    return plt.imshow(tensor)

content_image_tensor = image_to_tensor(content_path)
style_image_tensor = image_to_tensor(style_path)
hub_module = hub.load('https://tfhub.dev/google/magenta/arbitrary-image-stylization-v1-256/2')
combined_result = hub_module(tf.constant(content_image_tensor), tf.constant(style_image_tensor))[0]
result=tensor_to_image(combined_result)
```

Here is the error:

```
runfile('C:/Users/Sriram/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/Sriram/.spyder-py3')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Sriram\.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 30, in <module>
    content_image_tensor = image_to_tensor(content_path)

  File "C:\Users\Sriram\.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 20, in image_to_tensor
    img = tf.image.resize(img, [720, 512])

  File "C:\Users\Sriram\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\image_ops_impl.py", line 1182, in resize_images
    skip_resize_if_same=True)

  File "C:\Users\Sriram\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\image_ops_impl.py", line 1029, in _resize_images_common
    raise ValueError('\'images\' contains no shape.')

ValueError: 'images' contains no shape
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code runs fine on TensorFlow 2.2, so I'm assuming you're hitting a [somewhat known issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8551) with `decode_image` on TensorFlow 1.x: When "generically" decoding an image, the shape is not returned - which makes the call to `resize()` fail. There's multiple ways to go about it.

### Making use of known image sizes

If you know the size of of your image(s) beforehand, you can force a size onto the Tensor using the [`set_shape(shape)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor#set_shape) method (and *then* resize it):

```py
img = tf.io.read_file(path_to_img)
img = tf.image.decode_image(img, channels=3, dtype=tf.float32)
    
# Workaround
img.set_shape([width, height, 3])

img = tf.image.resize(img, [720, 512])
img = img[tf.newaxis, :]
```

### Making use of known image formats

If you know that all your images are JPEG, you can use `decode_jpeg` instead, which behaves a bit better:

```py
img = tf.io.read_file(path_to_img)

# Workaround
img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, np.float32)

img = tf.image.resize(img, [720, 512])
img = img[tf.newaxis, :]
```

### Using resize with cropping and padding

Alternatively, you may try using [tf.image.resize_with_crop_or_pad](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/resize_with_crop_or_pad) which apparently works around that issue:

```py
img = tf.io.read_file(path_to_img)
img = tf.image.decode_image(img, channels=3, dtype=tf.float32)
    
# Workaround
img = tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(img, 720, 512)

img = img[tf.newaxis, :]
```

---

There's one caveat though: The code assumes that all operations are executed eagerly, which is the default on TensorFlow 2.x, but not on TensorFlow 1.x. As a result of that, the `tensor_to_image(tensor)` function will fail because the provided Tensor cannot be simply converted into an NumPy array. To fix this, you can [enable eager execution](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/enable_eager_execution) at the start of your script by running

```py
tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()
```

---

On a side note - you can make use of [`tf.image.convert_image_dtype()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/convert_image_dtype) and [`tf.squeeze()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/squeeze) to convert your image back:

```py
def tensor_to_image(tensor):
    tensor = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(tensor, np.uint8)
    tensor = tf.squeeze(tensor)

    plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
    plt.axis('off')
    return plt.imshow(tensor)
```

This will make sure that all values properly saturate (you won't have values outside `0..1` when converting to `np.float32`, for example) and gets rid of the somewhat magic `[0]` indexing.